# How to use Link_to with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-resources

I am a totally newbie in Rails.

I have created a web application, I can access through `/posts/123/comments/` or `/posts/123/comments/new`, but i don't know how to use link_to in the index view to show a concrete comment, when i try to link it, appears "no route" or "undefined symbol".

I have a nested have_many relation between posts and comments defined in the models and in the `routes.rb` and  `post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/sensors(.:format)`          `comments#index` appears when I execute rake routes.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After trying all of the answers it didnt completely work, but i found a way to resolve it.
In a first moment, I used

> *post_comments_url(@post,comment)*

where comment is the item inside a @post.each.

It generates a "strange" route, using . instead / like "post/34/comments.2", i fixed it using the singular form:

> *post_comment_url(@post,comment)*

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 12):

If you have defined nested resources (and of course your models `Comment` and `Post` are associated)

```
resources :posts do
 resources :comments
end
```

You can link a comment as following

```
<!-- /posts/:post_id/comments/:id -->
<%= link_to 'Show', [@comment.post, @comment] %>
```

I've written a [full example of nested resources in a past blog post](http://blog.8thcolor.com/en/2011/08/nested-resources-with-independent-views-in-ruby-on-rails/)

Comment: I have changed my code to

<% @posts.each do |item| %>

  <tr>
    <td><%= item.nombre %></td>
    <td><%= item.info %></td>


    <td><%= link_to 'Show', [@comment.post, @comment] %></td>
    
  </tr>
<% end %>

and it doesnt run... appear a undefined method post.

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: That's probably because your `Comment` model is not associated to `Post`. You should have `belongs_to :post` in your `Comment` model. If not, it's normal it's undefined. You can also replace `@comment.post` with the `Post` object containing the comment (probably `item` in your case).

Comment: That's not working for me: it complains that `post_comment_path` is undefined (the routing that shows in `rake routes` is `post_comments`, plural)

Answer (score 1):

Get method name from the first column of

```
   rake routes
```

And pass the ids accordingly. And of course suffix the method name with `_path` ir `_url` 
To know more, visit the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the answer of toch, you can debug your link_to call with help of the Rails console.

For this, you need to load the view helpers in the console:

```
irb(main):001:0> include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
=> Object
irb(main):002:0> helper.link_to "posts", app.posts_path
=> "<a href=\"/posts\">foo</a>"
```

Another tool, similar to Rake routes for route debugging is: https://github.com/schneems/sextant